# Use Bash in Linux to get filename and delete similarly named files

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to look trough a directory and remove duplicate files based on filename. I was doing this with the following code:

```
    for i in `seq 1 10`;
    do
        rm "$d"/*\($i\).mp3
    done
```

This keeps song.mp3 and deletes song(1).mp3, song(2).mp3 and so on for up to 10 duplicates.

However, I realized that the original file is not the one without the duplicate (1).mp3 or (2).mp3 appended but rather the file with the highest duplicate number (earliest modification date), which in this case would be song(2).mp3. This is because for some reason the program i'm using renames the original file to song(1).mp3 and names the newest file song.mp3.

So what I want to do in the above case is remove song.mp3 and song(1).mp3 and mv song(2).mp3 to song.mp3 so that its modification date does not change.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i="1"

# If song(1).mp3 doesn't exist, there's nothing to do.
if [[ -f "$d/($i)".mp3 ]]
then
   # Remove song.mp3
   rm "$d".mp3

   # If song(n+1).mp3 exists, delete song(n).mp3 
   j=$((i+1))
   while [[ -f "$d/($j)".mp3 ]]
   do
      rm "$d/($i)".mp3
      i=$j
      j=$((i+1))
   done

   # Move song(n).mp3 to song.mp3
   mv "$d/($i)".mp3 "$d".mp3
fi
```

Comment: This throws an error at line 10 and I'm unfamiliar with the syntax you are using here. The error is: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @TheNightman My bad. Those were typos. You can go to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html to understand that syntax.

Comment: @RSahu This requires manual input of `$d` which can be done automatically. Also you don't need that `while` loop. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24005688/171318

Comment: You can use ``((j=i+1))`` instead, I believe that it is more readable. Also you have to add ``--`` after mv and rm to make sure that it does not break for files with leading slashes (since we don't know what ``$d`` is. Please see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target . Also it might be a good idea to use quotes around the whole parameter, like this ``"$d.mp3"``, but it is a matter of taste :)

Answer (score 2):

This solution will work for all files and not just for something manually specified like `d="song"`
. I hope the code comments are self explaining:

```
# Iterate through all file name prefixes of candiates
while read prefix ; do

    [[ -z "$prefix" ]] && continue

    # Get the oldest file. (The one with the largest suffix value for this prefix)
    oldest=$(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$prefix(*).mp3" | sort -t\( -k2r | head -n1)

    # Overwrite the newest with the oldest file.
    mv -v "$oldest" "$prefix.mp3"

    # Delete the files between oldest and newest
    rm -fv "$prefix(*.mp3"

done <<< $(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*([0-9]+).mp3' -printf "%f"  |  cut -f 1 -d\(  | uniq)
```

Comment: Like your code to extract the prefixes from existing files instead of getting it from the user. It's amazing how we can come up with such varying methods to accomplish the same objective.

Comment: @RSahu Yeah, its nice that all solutions are completely different.

Comment: So this looks pretty good, and what I was actually looking for, but mv doesn't seem to work properly, throwing this error: `mv: cannot stat ‘’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Damn!! :) Really? I experienced the same during testing it. That's why I've added the `[[ -z "$prefix" ]] && continue` check and it started working for me. I've added it, because `find` will return a single empty line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use globbing and just move every copy over the original file:

```
FILE=./song
EXT=mp3
for f in $FILE*.$EXT
do
    mv $f $FILE.$EXT 
done
```

which will work, since [bash globs loop over files in alphanumeric order](https://superuser.com/questions/192280/does-bashs-match-files-in-alphanumeric-order).

Comment: This won't work if the numbers get into double digits, because `song(2).mp3` will be after `song(10).mp3`. You need natural sorting, not lexicographic sorting.

Answer (score 0):

how about the following(this will keep the file with the latest file modification time)

command ls -rt *\(*\).mp3 | while read -r file; do mv -f "$file" "${file/(*)/}"; done

or safer: change "${file/(*)/}" to "${file%(*).mp3}.mp3"

Comment: So this looks like it should work for me. It is essentially the same as `mv file1 file2` and then `rm *\(*\).mp3` which is perfect and works in the terminal. But I cant find the problem in your code causing this to not happen. The code above just seems to rename the oldest file as `file .mp3` and leaving `file.mp3`

Comment: you want to save oldest one? then should use `command ls -t` (remove -r). but I don't see any reason of getting an extra space between 'file' and the dot. tested on my server which works well. is the filename "song(1).mp3" or "song (1).mp3"?